# Centralizers of factor group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ be a normal subgroup of it and $x\in G-K$. What is the relation between ${C_G(x)}K/K$ and $C_{G/K}(xK)$? When they are equal?

Comment: They can never be equal as they are subgroups of two different groups. Do you mean when the preimage of the latter is equal to the first?

Comment: I want to edit the question. Thank you.

Comment: You want $C_G(x)K/K$ for the first one, as $K$ need not be contained in the centralizer.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Sorry

Comment: I would think that $C_G(x)K/K$ is always contained in $C_{G/K}(xK)$. If $g\in G$ and $x$ commute, then  surely so do $gK$ and $xK$. OTOH, for $gK$ to be in $C_{G/K}(xK)$ we only need that $[g,x]\in K$. For example, if $K=[G,G]$, then $C_{G/K}(xK)=G/K$ for any $x$ because $G/K$ is abelian. But $C_G(x)K$ may still be a proper subgroup. Let $G$ be the quaternion group $Q_8$ and $x=i$ for a concrete example.